# What is this tool for?

Tags: tools

I recently found this in my cycling shirt. I don't know where it came from, and what it is used for. It reads "Simson" on the other side, but I have no clue what I could use it for. Does it have anything to do with spokes?

[image: Simson tool]

Comment: Looks like a (very cheap) spoke wrench to me.

Comment: In that case I would guess that it may have been part of a repair set in a small box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a spoke wrench.

Similar to this one:

http://www.btosports.com/p/bikemaster-spoke-wrench

Comment: And Simson (http://en.hollandbikeshop.com/bicycle-tools-maintenance/bicycle-tools/spoke-tools/simson-spoke-key/) is a brand of bike tools so this is likely correct. Probably this was part of an emergency repair kit.